# Is there a way to combine several paragraphs into one?

Tags: javascript, excel, string, merge

There is a daily report which is filled each day. There is a fixed point on a work site and someone takes notes at that point each day.

I have an excel spreadsheet which contains each day's observations (few sentences each day).

The thing is that many days can often have the exact same observation written down.

Is there a way where I can select these 30 or so cells (for the month) and combine them into one single paragraph which summarises all that information?

It is just a bit tedious and time-consuming to go through each day one by one to pick out the similarities or differences etc.

It would be great if there is a solution for this within excel, but I have access to a bit of javascript too.

Thank you!

Comment: Please post an example of input and desired result.

Comment: Hi, for example maybe something like this:

Comment: Input:

Low level litter detected
Low level litter detected

Medium level litter detected
Low level odour detected from the cell

Medium level noise from plant
Low level noise detected from machinery

Output:
Low to medium levels of litter detected.
Low level odour detected from the cell.
Medium level noise from plant.
Low level noise detected from machinery.

Comment: An example in tables  embedded in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If your daily observations are in separate cells & you have office 365, you could nest `UNIQUE()` inside `TEXTJOIN()`, like this: `TEXTJOIN(UNIQUE())`.